# esmtp application not authorizing with smtp server

Tags: linux, email, smtp

I have a problem with the esmtp application that I really hope you help me with.

The thing is that I am trying to connect to a smtp server at one.com which needs authorization. But it seems like that esmtp won’t issue the AUTH command.

I have set up the `esmtprc` file as follow:

```
hostname = send.one.com:25
username = "username"
password = "password"
```

I issue this command which fails:

```
echo "Hello" | esmtp -f xxx@xxx.dk -v -C esmtprc -X smtplog.txt xxx@xxx.se
```

The log file now includes:

```
S: 220 csmtp3.one.com ESMTP
C: EHLO xxx
S: 250-csmtp3.one.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 104857600
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
C: MAIL FROM:<xxx@xxx.dk>
S: 250 2.1.0 Ok
C: RCPT TO:<xxx@xxx.se>
S: 553 5.7.1 <xxx@xxx.dk>: Sender address rejected: not logged in
C: QUIT
S: 221 2.0.0 Bye
```

I was expecting an AUTH command just before the “MAIL FROM” command.

I don’t know which version of esmtp that I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The sasl-plain.so couldn't be found. When it was made available, the authentication was no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `libesmtp` is refusing to use plaintext authentication without SSL. Try setting `starttls` as well.

Comment: But enabling starttls requires setting up some certificates. Is that really necessary?

Comment: @Munk No, you shouldn't need any (specific) certificates on your end if you just want encryption. Did you try?